# Pyspark - Calling function within lambda causes import error

Tags: python, cassandra, pyspark

I'm trying to do something fairly simple. I've got a datetime object as part of my dataframe, and when doing a map, I'd like to format the date a specific way. I've created a custom function:

```
def format_date(dt):
    """Set this for date formatting. dt is datetime."""
    return dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

And then later on, I use this in my map call (x.t is a datetime object):

```
unique = df.map(lambda x: (x.id,[[format_date(x.t),x.val]]))\
      .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)\
      .collectAsMap()
```

This causes the following exception *when submitted as a job*:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 9, preteckt1.softlayer.com): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named analysis
```

Note that my script name is "run_analyses.py", and imports all of the functions from "analysis.py". I submit the job with

```
/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --total-executor-cores 12 run_analyses.py
```

The strangest thing is that it works perfectly fine if I copy the code to an interactive pyspark session (or if I remove the format_date call). I can get around this by creating a new column and using UDF on my format_date function to create a new column, but I'd like to know why this approach is failing.

I've pasted the more complete code below.

**Edit**: It appears it succeeds if I run the code directly from analysis.py, but fails if I run it from run_analysis.py. I've altered the code below to more accurately show this.

run_analyses.py

```
import datetime, json, math, subprocess
from os.path import expanduser
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext
from analysis import *

sc = SparkContext()
sqlCtx = HiveContext(sc)
ids = {}
...
my_func(sqlCtx,ids)
```

analysis.py

```
def my_func(sqlCtx,ids):
    df = sqlCtx.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").load(table="table_name", keyspace="keyspace_name").select("id","t","val")
    df = df.filter((df.t > last_week)&(df.t < now))
    df = df.filter(df.val > 0)
    write_vals(df)
    ...

def write_vals(df):
    unique = df.map(lambda x: (x.id,[[format_date(x.t),x.val]]))\
            .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)\
            .collectAsMap()
    ...
    return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in the traceback:

```
ImportError: No module named analysis
```

PySpark is telling you that the worker process doesn't have access to analysis.py. When you initialize the SparkContext you can pass a list of files that should be copied to the worker:

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name", pyFiles=['MyFile.py', 'lib.zip', 'app.egg'])
```

More information:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html#standalone-use

Comment: That did it! Thanks :)

altering my sc instantiation to sc = SparkContext(pyFiles=['analysis.py']) fixed it.